# Adding multiple elements to list in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I made this method to set parameters from a text file:

```
def set_params(self, params, previous_response=None):
        if len(params) > 0:
            param_value_list = params.split('&')
            self.params = {
                param_value.split()[0]: json.loads(previous_response.decode())[param_value.split()[1]] if
                param_value.split()[0] == 'o' and previous_response else param_value.split()[1]
                for param_value in param_value_list
            }
```

When i call this method for example like this:

```
apiRequest.set_params("lim 5 & status active")

//now self.params={"lim" : 5, "status" : "active"}
```

it works well. Now I want to be able to add the same parameter multiple times, and when that happens, set the param like a list:

```
apiRequest.set_params("lim 5 & status active & status = other")

//I want this: self.params={"lim" : 5, "status" : ["active", "other"]}
```

How can I modify this method beautifully? All I can think of is kinda ugly... I am new with python

Comment: Stack Overflow probably isn't the best place for this kind of question. Maybe you could post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Comment: Start with a regular loop, overcomplicated comprehension expressions are rarely beautiful.

Comment: Readability... take for example `param_value.split()`, it occours 4 times. Why don't you do a preprocessing step with `split` first?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath thanks but what kind of preprocessing do you suggest? can you post some code?

Comment: `map(str.split, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Just write it as simple and straightforward as you can.  That is usually the best approach.  In my code, below, I made one change to your requirements: all values are a list, some may have just one element in the list.

In this method I apply the following choices and techniques:

- decode and parse the previous response only once, not every time it is referenced
- start with an empty dictionary
- split each string only once: this is faster because it avoids redundant operations and memory allocations, and (even more importantly) it is easier to read because the code is not repetitive
- adjust the `value` according to the special-case
- use [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to obtain the current list of values, if present, or set a new empty list object if it is not present
- append the new value to the list of values

```py
def set_params(self, params, previous_response=None):
    if len(params) <= 0:
        return
    previous_data = json.loads(previous_response.decode())
    self.params = {}
    for param_value in params.split('&'):
        key, value = param_value.split()
        if key == 'o' and previous_response:
            value = previous_data[value]

        values = self.params.setdefault(key, [])
        values.append(value)
# end set_params()
```

> Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place.
>   Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by
>   definition, not smart enough to debug it.
>
> ```
>    — Brian W. Kernighan and P. J. Plauger in The Elements of Programming Style.
> ```
>
> *Reference: http://quotes.cat-v.org/programming/*